# Determining datetime filter from a different time zone - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Iam in process of generating a report for my team which requires me to select rows in sql server based on today's date (IST Zone)

This report is strictly based on my working hours (06.00 IST to 22.00 IST).

The server is in US and its in CST zone.

For eg., Today's date is 04/04/2013. When i start working on 06.00 IST its equivalent to (04/03/2013 19.30 CST) and when i complete my work it will be (04/04/2013 11.30 CST).

So what i require here is a filter, which will allow me to filter records based on the above condition.

Note: I tried the below query, but does not work to my expectation when both the timezones are in same date.

```
DECLARE     @date DATETIME,@startdate DATETIME,@starthour DATETIME
DECLARE    @enddate DATETIME,@endhour DATETIME,@newdate DATETIME  

SET   @date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()-1), 0)
SET   @starthour = DATEADD(HOUR,19,@date)
set @startdate= DATEADD(MINUTE,30,@starthour)

Set @newdate= DATEADD(DD,1,@date)
SET   @endhour = DATEADD(HOUR,11,@newdate)
set @enddate= DATEADD(MINUTE,30,@endhour)

select @startdate, @enddate
select * from dbo.MyTable where TIMESTAMP Between @startdate and @enddate
```

Since this report needs to be generated on a hourly basis, i require some help on getting my datetime calculations correct even when the dates are in sync.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and which rows should be included? Trying to convert data between timezones between UTC and one timezone is hard enough, never mind adding in a second timezone on the other side of UTC and a half hour shift on top of that.

Comment: Also consider that for part of the year your data in CST will actually be in CDT, so it will be an hour different. Does your time zone obey the same DST rules as US Central Time? That may reduce some of the complexity if you know your work day will always be x hours + y minutes different, regardless of DST

Comment: Why would you unaccept the only answer from the only person with any input into your problem, three years later? I don't care about the points, I'm genuinely curious how you came to the decision that this solved your problem at the time, but three years later, suddenly doesn't... If your requirements have changed, that's probably a new question; if some bug or other issue has been found in my solution, a comment is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the same DST rules as US Central Time, and therefore your work day *always* starts at 19:30 yesterday Central Time, and your work day is always 16 hours, then you should be able to do this:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, -270, 
  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

SELECT columns FROM dbo.table
  WHERE [TIMESTAMP] BETWEEN @start AND DATEADD(HOUR, 16, @start);
```

If you follow different DST rules then you will need to adjust this calculation depending on the date and when the rules are different. You will probably be best to use a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) for this.

Note that `TIMESTAMP` is a really bad choice for a column name not only because it is vague but also since it is a [future reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(SQL.100).aspx) and represents a data type that has nothing to do with date or time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. Regarding the "Timestamp" column, Yes, i do agree with what you suggest, but this column was created by someone else and is in place for quite sometime. Changing that now is quite a costly affair. Will keep this mind when we create new tables.